# Why does boost::call_traits pass small objects like pair<char, char> by reference?

Tags: c++, boost, parameter-passing

I need a way to decide whether to pass an arbitrary type T by copy or by const-reference (e.g., if T is small enough then copy if, otherwise pass it by const-reference). To avoid reinventing the wheel, I tried out Boost Call Traits.

As expected, primitive types are passed by value, and complex types like `std::string` are passed by reference. However, tiny non-primitive types are also passed by reference, e.g., `std::pair<char, char>`, which does not seem to be the best choice. I assumed that everything up to `sizeof(void*)` would be passed by value.

Generally, the Boost libraries are of high quality, so maybe I am missing something.

Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/call_traits.hpp>

template <typename TYPE>
void test(const char* type_name)
{
  typedef typename boost::call_traits<TYPE>::param_type T;  
  if(std::is_reference<T>::value)        
    std::cout << type_name << " is passed by reference (sizeof=" << sizeof(TYPE) << ")\n"; 
  else 
    std::cout << type_name << " is passed by value (sizeof=" << sizeof(TYPE) << ")\n"; 
}

int main()
{
  test<short>("short");
  test<int>("int");
  test<double>("double");
  test<std::string>("std::string");
  test<long long>("long long");
  test<std::pair<int, int>>("std::pair<int, int>");
  test<std::pair<short, short>>("std::pair<short, short>");
  test<std::pair<char, char>>("std::pair<char, char>");
  test<std::tuple<char, char>>("std::tuple<char, char>");
  test<std::tuple<char, char, char, char>>("std::tuple<char, char, char, char>");
  test<std::pair<long long, long long>>("std::pair<long long, long long>");
  return 0;
}
```

And here are the results (Boost 1.50, g++ 4.7.2):

```
short is passed by value (sizeof=2)
int is passed by value (sizeof=4)
double is passed by value (sizeof=8)
std::string is passed by reference (sizeof=8)
long long is passed by value (sizeof=8)
std::pair<int, int> is passed by reference (sizeof=8)
std::pair<short, short> is passed by reference (sizeof=4)
std::pair<char, char> is passed by reference (sizeof=2)
std::tuple<char, char> is passed by reference (sizeof=2)
std::tuple<char, char, char, char> is passed by reference (sizeof=4)
std::pair<long long, long long> is passed by reference (sizeof=16)
```

Comment: Good question.  Serious stab in the dark -- maybe because boost cannot trust that the copy constructor of a non-basic type will be a simple bit copy?  So a sub-pointer sized class might have a really expensive copy operation.  Even knowing your class has a default copy constructor wouldn't be enough -- you'd also have to know that all of the contents have default copy constructors all the way down to primitive types.  Maybe one of the new C++0x types of structs match this meaning?

Comment: Good point, I did not think about user-defined copy constructors or types where copying may the semantic (e.g, a std::atomic that is modified by another thread).

However, if the type is a POD and small enough, it should be safe to pass it by value. Unfortunately, `std::is_pod<std::pair<char, char>>::value` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Traits is a generic library and must work with any user-defined types. To decide whether it is faster to pass an arbitrary type by value requires extra knowledge which is beyond the scope of the library. So, the conservative approach of always passing by value when in doubt, is reasonable.

Although it should be possible to extend it to improve the support for commonly used STL types (e.g., `std::pair`, `std::tuple`, `std::array`), there is no generic way to do so.